# Какой должен быть массив PHP для передачи в JS

Tags: php

Как создать подобную конструкцию (data) на PHP для передачи в JS? Это массив массивов ключ-значение? Как его преобразовать потом, чтобы просто переменной PHP можно было вставить?

```
function($) { $('.fotorama').fotorama({
    data: [
      {href: '1.jpg', thumb: '2.jpg'},
      {href: '3.jpg', thumb: '4.jpg'}
    ]
 });
```

Comment: json_encode() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто делаете ассоциативный массив и преобразуете через `json_encode`

```
$data = [
    ['href' => 'qqq', 'thumb' => 'ttt'], 
    ['href' => 'rrr', 'thumb' => 'mmm'], 
];

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Comment: `header("Content-type: application/json")` еще для полного